Is it possible to explain regression or classification, interpolation and generation using a single model structure?
Neural network is established as an universal approximator of all machine learning models. Further, double descent phenomenon in a neural network propagates the journey of regression to interpolation via interpolating point.
Is it possible to propagate it further to generation modelling?

This might be possible via multi-modal neural networks. See Multimodal Deep Learning

May you explain further?
